# ItemsControl layout won't display a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to display a collection of items in an ItemsControl layout which is placed in another userControl but it wont display anything here is what i tried knowing that most of this code is copied from a working examples that is working i just cant figure out what is wrong as am not experienced in wpf :

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="cafeteria.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cafeteria"
        xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:cafeteria._shared"
        xmlns:_pages="clr-namespace:cafeteria._pages"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="منظومة الكافتريا "
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="19*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="#be2116" Orientation="Vertical">
            <!-- add the control buttons-->
            <local1:ApplicationControls></local1:ApplicationControls>
            <!--app name-->
            <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="./_Content/logo.png" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="80"></Image>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="White">منظومة</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="20" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Light" TextAlignment="right" Foreground="White">الكافتريا</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <local1:SideBar Margin="0,50,0,0"></local1:SideBar>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Background="#fe8d00" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></StackPanel>

            <_pages:Food Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></_pages:Food>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Food user control xaml file

```
<UserControl x:Class="cafeteria._pages.Food"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:cafeteria._pages"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding products}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=name}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Food.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace cafeteria._pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Food.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Food : UserControl
    {

       public List<product> products;
        public Food()
        {
            this.products = new List<product>()
            {
                new product{ name = "chips"},
                 new product{ name = "pipsi"},
            };

            InitializeComponent();
        }


    }

    public class product
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding products}"` in the UserControl's XAML expects a public property `products` in the DataContext of the UserControl. This source collection would usually not be declared by the UserControl itself, but instead passed via an inherited DataContext, e.g. the MainWindow's DataContext that holds the MainWindow's view model. How is your control supposed to work? Shall the product collection be passed to the UserControl when it is declared in the MainWindow XAML?

Comment: And if the UserControl contains nothing more than an ItemsControl, why do you have it all? Why not directly use an ItemsControl instead of a UserControl?

Comment: @Clemens i have 4 UserControls which acts as pages for this project. What i want to do is that when i navigate to one of these usercontrols form the navbar it loads the data form the database when it is initialized

Comment: Then instead of binding the ItemsSource of its ItemsControl, the UserControl could just set it in its initialization code. Assign a name like `<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">` and set the ItemsSource property after InitializeComponent was called (e.g. in a Loaded event handler) like `itemsControl.ItemsSource = products;`

Comment: @Clemens thanks alot it worked could you please add it as an answer so i could approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data to be displayed in the UserControl's ItemsControl is not supposed to be supplied from an inherited DataContext (e.g. a Window's view model), but instead internally retrieved by the control's code logic, you could directly set the ItemsSource property in code behind.

Most simply by assigning an `x:Name` to the ItemsControl

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
```

and then accessing the generated field in code behind, after InitializeComponent was called:

```
itemsControl.ItemsSource = new List<product>()
{
    new product{ name = "chips" },
    new product{ name = "pipsi" },
};
```

---

As a note, you should under no circumstances set the UserControl's DataContext to itself. In case you would later add bindable properties to the control, setting the DataContext this way would break any Bindings of its properties to properties of a view model object in the inherited DataContext, e.g. something like

```
<_pages:Food MyProperty="{Binding SomeViewModelProperty}"/>
```

would not work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

In order for your sample to work, you could for example bind the control to itself.

```
<UserControl x:Class="cafeteria._pages.Food"
             ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

This way you could directly bind to contained properties. For this to work you will need to make your products-field to a property.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
```

Like Clemens already mentioned, binding a contrl to itself is not a good approach, I just wanted to point out what is missing in your sample in order to work.

Alternatively you could also set the ItemsSource property from code behind (i.e. in ItemsCotrol.Loaded).

That being said, I think it would be better to transfer the logic which loads the data to a separate class and bind the result from your window.

Comment: While `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` makes no sense at all, `ItemsSource="{Binding products}"` will also not work, because `products` is not a public property in the UserControl's DataContext, and it is not supposed to be one.

Comment: @Clemens: I don't know what you mean. By putting the control into its own DataContext, you can reference the property like done above. Please try it before downvoting the answer. The sample works, even though it's surely not the prettiest one.

Comment: You should never set a UserControl's DataContext to itself. Doing so will break any Bindings of its properties to properties of a view model object in the inherited DataContext. While you may argue that OP's control does not expose any bindable properties, setting its DataContext this way is still a bad advice. Simply don't do it.

Comment: Besides that, the sample does not work, because `products` is a field, not a property.

Comment: @Clemens: Yes, you are right with this. This is exactly what I wanted to say with the last sentence of my answer. I just pointed out first what was missing in his sample in order to work, then provided another solution. I also mentioned, that it's not a good approach to load the data inside of the control anyway. Regarding the field: Ok, yes. Thats true indeed. I overlooked that. I will add that information to the answer. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Clemens: That would be another way to achieve the same behavior. And no, noone is required to manually set this each time the control is created, as this obviously happens automatically when it's declared in XAML. And I still don't think that it's nonsense as you call it. It's a working solution, even if one should definitely go other ways to solve such a problem.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I misread where you actually placed that assignment. But as already explained, explicitly setting a UserControl's DataContext is just wrong, whether setting it to the control itself or some private view model.

Comment: @Clemens: Yes, we both agree that one shouldn't do that, as there are many other and far better options to resolve such a problem.